# Blender Bump Map Not Working/Applying!

Tags: texturing, bump

I've been searching online for 3+ hours trying to figure this problem out, I finally have to post my problem to search for an answer.

When I apply my bump map to an object's texture, the map doesn't read the non-color height information coming from the image. I thought this was a software problem so I did a fresh install of the latest release of Blender (I did not install the beta version). I did the same steps as last time and it still did not work.

Also, note that when I apply a bump map the texture of the image does change to show a collection of cubes on the surface of the texture. Look at the images below to get a better idea of my situation.

I checked all of my drivers and they are all up to date. I'm stumped and I could really use a helpful solution to this problem. Thanks.

[Updated Blender File](https://easyupload.io/k2hzrp)

[Image of what the texture is supposed to look like](https://easyupload.io/u0mlbv)

[image: General View of Problem]

[image: Nodes]

[image: Bump Bands but no Bumps]

[texturenotworking](https://easyupload.io/e5mb3e)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108430/discussion-on-question-by-moeskie-blender-bump-map-not-working-applying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Principled's Normal* socket (and all other *Normal* sockets) is used to fake 3D. It is useful to save a lot of memory and calculation, because you can keep a low-poly object. The bumps we see are fake bump, meaning only shadows, the topology is not displaced for real, you'll notice it if you move your object, a plane will remain flat. You can either plug *Bump* or *Normal* map nodes into this *Normal* socket.

(For real displacement, meaning you want to add real 3D effect to the topology without actually moving any face in *Edit* mode, you need to have enough geometry, otherwise Blender wont be able to move any face. You can either do it with the *Shader Editor* and plug the *Bump* node into the *Displacement* node, or use the modifier called *Displacement*. With these methods you'll see a real 3D effect. But it's another topic.)

So the basic setup for a fake bump effect is the following one: Prepare your color image and its bump version. The bump version is a b&w picture, you can use a software like CrazyBump to make it, or just convert your color image to b&w for the moment.

[image]
[image]

Now setup this node organization, plug the color image into the *Base Color* input of the *Principled BSDF*, plug the bump image into a *Bump* node, into the *Normal* input of the *Principled BSDF*.

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

To see the bump effect only, unplug the color image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, always use non-color data instead of sRGB when using maps. sRGB is only for color image textures.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I must've forgotten to change it to noncolor data. I just changed it with no effect on the problem I've had with no bumps/depth shown on the shader.

Comment: I was confused about that, I see bumps on the shader, that's whz I figured, they were only wrong, or taken from the wrong channel. Can you highlight your problem a bit more, then I can probably refine my answer.

Comment: When you zoom into the texture there is no 3D aspect to the texture. The texture is completely flat. I've seen others do bump mapping and it has a more profound 3D effect than what I've come up with. I also have double-checked all of the nodes that make up this shader. To see my problem you can also download my project file.