# Why is my distorted noise texture not giving me it's correct bump normal information?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, procedural, shader-nodes

below I added an image of what I mean.

My noise texture gets distorted, but for some reason when plugging in the Fac or Color output into another bump node, The distortion is gone..

I'd love to know why this happens, have I maybe overlooked something?
How can I make this work..

Thanks for reading

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell what is going on without seeing the entire node setup, especially what you are plugging these nodes into?

Comment: Hi Scottywood, the output of the nodes in both setups go into a viewer node that goes into the material output of the material.
In the upper setup I'm 'viewing' the fac output of the noise texture node.
In the below setup I'm 'viewing' the normal output of the bump node

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish? Plugging your bump map into the material output only outputs a color, not a bump. You also have two bump map nodes in your nodes, which isn't really how you're supposed to use them. Take a look a look at this post, this is how you're supposed to use the bump map node,  It's plugged into the Normal socket of a Shader node, which is then plugged in the material output. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179668/blender-bump-map-not-working-applying

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Basically in the above pics I distorted the noise texture using bump normal information to get a height based 'accurate' distortion of texture. For some reason though, when plugging that Fac/Color output of the distorted noise into another bump node, the bump node ignores the distortion I did to the noise's object coordinates. It doesn't matter anymore though since I found a work around using the displacement input (set to bump only). Thanks a lot for the responses though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically found a workaround that kinda gives the result I was looking for. With the below setup you can distort texture based on height and get correct information for bump mapping

[image: basic voronoi and noise for demo]

Comment: why do you mix texture coordinates ? :D

Comment: To influence (distort) the object coordinates of the noise texture based on what I fed through the displacement socket input